# Best Collection for Fast String Lookup

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I need a list of strings and a way to quickly determine if a string is contained within that list.

To enhance lookup speed, I considered `SortedList` and `Dictionary`; however, both work with `KeyValuePair`s when all I need is a single `string`.

I know I could use a `KeyValuePair` and simply ignore the `Value` portion. But I do prefer to be efficient and am just wondering if there is a collection better suited to my requirements.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or higher, use [`HashSet<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Failing that, a `Dictionary<string, byte>` (or whatever type you want for the `TValue` type parameter) would be faster than a `SortedList` if you have a lot of entries - the latter will use a binary search, so it'll be O(log n) lookup, instead of O(1).

Comment: @Jonathan: Agreed - such is life though. In .NET 4 there's an interface to represent sets (`ISet<T>`) and also another option in `SortedSet<T>` (which again wouldn't be particularly useful in this case).

Comment: I was just looking back at this. A O(1) lookup is fast indeed. However, I'm guessing this collection implements some sort of hashing. So doesn't O(1) assume no collisions? (BTW, I'm working my way through your book.)

Comment: @Jonathan: It's O(1) if the hash is reasonable, so there aren't *too* many collisions.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to know if a string is in the set use `HashSet<string>`

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a job for

```
 var keys = new HashSet<string>();
```

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx): The Contains function has O(1) complexity.

But you should be aware that it does not give an error for duplicates when adding.

Comment: To be more precise the Add method does not throw an exception but it does return true if the key was added and false if it was already present.

Answer (score 3):

[`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) is like a `Dictionary`, but with only keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like rolling your own data structure, use a Trie.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

worst-case is if the string is present: O(length of string)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a bit late to this party, but I was running into an issue where our systems were running slow. After profiling we found out there was a LOT of string lookups happening with the way we had our data structures structured.

So we did some research, [came across these benchmarks](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-collection-for-string-lookups), did our own tests, and have switched over to using SortedList now.

```
if (sortedlist.ContainsKey(thekey))
{   
//found it.
}
```

Even though a Dictionary proved to be faster, it was less code we had to refactor, and the performance increase was good enough for us.

Anyway, wanted to share the website in case other people are running into similar issues. They do comparisons between data structures where the string you're looking for is a "key" (like HashTable, Dictionary, etc) or in a "value" (List, Array, or in a Dictionary, etc) which is where ours are stored.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old as hell, but I just had to solve the same problem, only for a very small set of strings(between 2 and 4).

In my case, I actually used manual lookup over an array of strings which turned up to be much faster than `HashSet<string>`(I benchmarked it).

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.propertiesToIgnore.Length; i++)
{
    if (this.propertiesToIgnore[i].Equals(propertyName))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note, that it is better than hash set for only for tiny arrays!

EDIT: works only with a manual `for` loop, do not use LINQ, details in comments

Comment: Yes, `HashSet<>` has some overhead. I would only recommend it when searching larger collections. BTW, your code could be shortened to something like `return PropertiesToIgnore.Any(p => p.Equals(propertyName))`

Comment: Unfortunately, using Linq slows down execution by a factor of 10! Benchmark results `ArrayManualLoop: 6.018 ns` `ArrayLinq: 59.171 ns`. Linq thorns the processor cache apart, and all the possible gains are lost.